# Running a loop to see which industries have more than 30 data points

Tags: python

Hello I am a python beginner looking for some guidance. I have some data and would like to see which of my industries have more than 30 data points. I looked into running a loop but I am not sure how to go about this. Can someone point me in that direction?

Comment: can you add code you tried so far and show an expected output

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the way your data is formatted. If your data points are simply given in a list, you can easily do this with len():

Let's assume the list is formatted as a list of lists `[[],[],[],[]]`, where the inner lists, representing your industries, are populated with your data points: ``

```
data = [[3, 2, 1], [1], [1, 2, 3, ...], [...]]

for industry in data:
    if len(industry) > 30:
        ...do what you need...
```

The exact same can however also be used if your industries are given as a dict: `{"ind_1": [1, 2, 3], "ind_2": [...]}`. But well, it all depends on the way your data is formatted.